# Passing data through angular components with highcharts

Tags: angular

This one is a very basic example showing a highcharts picture with angular 7.
Instead of passing the values directly to the data[] object from options, I want to do it through a value declared in app.component, using @input decorator in hello-component.
But running ng serve i am getting "Cannot read property 'direct' of undefined" error. Some help, please? Thank you very much!

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'passComponent';
  aces: number;
  
  constructor() {
    this.aces = 5;
  }
}
```

hello-component.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello-component',
  templateUrl: './hello-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hello-component.component.css']
})
export class HelloComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() direct: number;

  public options: any = {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      height: 700
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Sample Scatter Plot'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return 'x: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b %y %H:%M:%S', this.x) + 'y: ' + this.y.toFixed(2);
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
       categories: ['RG', 'WM']
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Normal',
        
        data: (function() {
          var datos = [];
          for (let i = 0; i <=1; i += 1) {
            datos.push({
              x: i,
              y: this.direct + i
            });
          }
          return datos;
        }())
        
      }    
    ]
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    Highcharts.chart('container', this.options);    
  }
}
```

hello-component.component.html

```js
<p>{{direct}} direct</p>
<div id="container"></div>
```

app.component.html

```js
<div>
  <!-- <app-hello-component direct="5"></app-hello-component> -->
  <app-hello-component [direct]="aces"></app-hello-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of Angular life cycle methods, you normally want to assign values `OnInit` (when component template has been initialized). It also makes sense to render element only when value has been initialized. So to correct this, you'd need to change your code to:

#### app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'passComponent';
  aces: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.aces = 5;
  }
}
```

#### app.component.html

```html
<div *ngIf="aces">
  <!-- <app-hello-component direct="5"></app-hello-component> -->
  <app-hello-component [direct]="aces"></app-hello-component>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm so sorry to inform you that still getting the same error. Thanks!

Comment: I have added the code constructor (direct: number) {}; in class HelloComponentComponent and see now no error from google console but the graphic is not showing...